# How to load an execute a jquery file using react?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't tell where the error is and it is not showing alert box onclick on button in jquery
There are two files

**INDEX.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import $ from '../node_modules/jquery'; 
import UsingJquery from './UsingJquery';

ReactDOM.render(   
                <>
                  <UsingJquery/>   
                </>,
                document.getElementById("root") 
);
```

**UsingJquery.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import $ from 'jquery';


const UsingJquery = () => {
    $('button').on('click',function (){ 
        alert('clicked')
    });

    return(
        <>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <button>Click me</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default UsingJquery;
```

Comment: As an aside, it is not recommended to reference modules in `node_modules` directly, as you have done in line 3 of your first example. Instead, reference the package name directly like you have done with the other imports.

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, welcome to stackoverflow. I have edited your question title to make it more relevant and removed the "please help me" from your post as it is not relevant to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching the DOM for the element before the component has created the element, returned it, and had it inserted into the DOM.

If you need to access rendered elements then you should use [a `useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import $ from "jquery";

export default function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect( () => {
    if (!buttonRef.current) return;
    $(buttonRef.current).on("click", function() { 
      alert('clicked'); 
    });
  }, [buttonRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hi</p>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, you should almost *always* avoid direct DOM access and use JSX in combination with state and props instead.

```
const click = () => {
    alert('clicked');
};

const NotUsingJquery = () => {
    return(
        <>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <button onClick={click}>Click me</button>
        </>
    )
}
```